# In my home we newly fixed a inverter given connected to 6 led bulb(10w each) 2 fans and for 1 extra socket. it is working fine for 1 year

Tags: electrical-panel

But now when I on the pc the bulb starts flickering. I think it is due to more power taken by pc so lights starts flickering. The electrician came and check and told when starting of pc it take more power so there is no problem in Inverter.

but now with out connecting the pc when lights is on its starts flickering and suddenly turn off some time and turn on. is there a problem with Inverter or due to overload or circuit.

please tell a solution..

Comment: Inverter? It doesn't seem likely that this is the term you intended to use

Comment: What is the output capacity from the inverter? What are the power requirements of the PC? Has the flicker happened _every_ time the PC is turned on, or have you been using the same PC for the last year and this is a new issue that started recently? Please [edit] pics of the name plate/label into your original question to make it easy for everyone to find.

Comment: Can you give us the nameplate watts and amps of each of the loads?  You can [edit] your question (from the same browser you posted it from). If you want to switch browsers, first register your account.

Comment: LED lights are somewhat pron to flicker. If the lamp is replaceable, try another.